# Groovy make a class implement an interface via metaprogramming

Tags: groovy

Can I make a class implement an interface via Groovy's compile-time metaprogramming, and if so, how? I know that I can implement the methods defined in an interface for a given class. But how can I then cast an object of that class to that interface type?

Let's say I have an interface

```
public interface MyInterface {
  void foo();
}
```

and a class

```
public class MyClass {

}
```

can I then provide a method `bar` with return type `MyInterface` that returns an instance of `MyClass` when called like

```
MyInterface mi = bar();
mi.foo();
```

and does not raise a `ClassCastException`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Groovy features a couple of runtime ways to solve that. For compile time, [`@Delegate`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Delegate.html) may be something to look at, besides implementing the interface, of course.

Anyway, you can coerce a class/map/closure to an interface easily. Here are some solutions:

#### 1. `as` operator

I think this is the best for your case. A class is coerced into an interface. It is similar to [Java proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

```
interface MyInterface {
  def foo()
}

class MyClass {
    def foo() { "foo" }
}

def bar() {
    return new MyClass() as MyInterface
}


MyInterface mi = bar()
assert mi.foo() == "foo"
```

#### 2. Map coercion

A map can be coerced into an interface. You need to forward the method signatures, but it also gives more control over what is invoked and how it is invoked.

```
def mapped() {
    def m = new MyClass()
    [foo: { m.foo() }] as MyInterface
}

MyInterface mi2 = mapped()
assert mi2.foo() == "foo"
```

#### 3. Anonymous class

Classical JDK < 8 style for a single method interface implementation.

```
def anonymous() {
    def m = new MyClass()
    new MyInterface() {
        def foo() {
            m.foo()
        }
    }
}

MyInterface mi3 = anonymous()
assert mi3.foo() == "foo"
```

#### 4. Closure coercion

This one works a lot like JDK 8 lambda coercion. In this case, the method is returning a method reference to `m.foo` coerced into `MyInterface`. Be aware closure coercion is way more powerful than this, being able to coerce into [abstract classes, concrete classes and splitting the atom](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/groovy-goodness-implicit-closure.html):

```
def coercion() {
    def m = new MyClass()
    m.&foo as MyInterface
}

MyInterface mi4 = coercion()
assert mi4.foo() == "foo"
```

#### 5. `@Delegate` with a factory for subclasses

**Update:** You can create a class which [`@Delegates`](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/groovy-goodness-delegate-to-simplify.html) all method invocations to an object which can respond to all interfaces without implementing them.

Note that if `MyClass` doesn't implement all needed methods, a compilation error is thrown.

For subclasses, you can use a factory method:

```
interface Foo { def foo() }
interface Bar { def bar() }
interface Baz { def baz() }

class MyClass {
    def foo() { "foo" }
    def bar() { "bar" }
    def baz() { "baz" }
}

class MySubClass extends MyClass {
    def foo() { "sub foo" }
}

class MyDelegate implements Foo, Bar, Baz {
    @Delegate MyClass my

    static getSub() {
        new MyDelegate(my : new MySubClass())
    }
}

MyDelegate.sub.with {
    assert foo() == "sub foo"
    assert bar() == "bar"
    assert baz() == "baz"
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Now that I think about it, my example is a bit too simple for what I actually need to achieve. I need to make this behaviour available to subclasses of `MyClass` as well. Also I need to be able to apply multiple interfaces to `MyClass` so that I can detect them with `instanceof`... I'll try to come up with a solution using your suggestions and post it to code review :)

Comment: @zero_cool added a 5th solution based on your comment. Tell me if it is of any help.

Comment: Ah, that is a really cool solution! Actually I still need to implement the methods of the interfaces in the delegate, but I tried that and it works :)
Now I only need to write a factory method that, when asked to instantiate `MySubclass` detects that the supertype is overidden and invokes the `getSub()` mehtod instead. One more thing, if I want to override `MySubclass` as well, I could then return a `new MyDelegate(my : new MySubDelegate())`, right?

Comment: You needed to implement the interface methods in `MyDelegate`? That's wrong, because that is exactly what `@Delegate` should do for you (at least in my example)

Comment: No, you shouldn't be able to use `new MyDelegate(my: new MySubDelegate())`, because `MySubDelegate` doesn't extend `MyClass` (unless you want to remove `MyClass` and have everything in `MyDelegate` class hierarchy instead)

Comment: Ah, I see. I also can't cast to a different class with `as`. I just hid the classes behind interfaces and applied an `as` coercion. This way, the nested delegate seems to work properly in [this example](http://pastebin.com/UExGH3vh). Edit: I also should make `MySubDelegate` extend `MyDelegate`.