# Groovy coercion to interface not known at compile-time

Tags: groovy, coercion

Some time ago I asked how [to make a class implement an interface that it doesn't implement by declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913394/groovy-make-a-class-implement-an-interface-via-metaprogramming).

One possibility is `as`-coercion:

```
interface MyInterface {
  def foo()
}

class MyClass {
    def foo() { "foo" }
}

def bar() {
    return new MyClass() as MyInterface
}


MyInterface mi = bar()
assert mi.foo() == "foo"
```

Now that I try to use it, I don't know what interface is needed at compile-time. I tried using generics like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
  def foo()
}

class MyClass {
    def foo() { "foo" }
}

class Bar {
    public static <T> T bar(Class<T> type) {
        return new MyClass() as T
    }
}


MyInterface mi = Bar.bar(MyInterface.class)
assert mi.foo() == "foo"
```

But it raises the following exception:

```
Cannot cast object 'MyClass@5c4a3e60' with class 'MyClass' to class 'MyInterface'
```

How can I coerce to an interface that is only known at run-time?

Comment: Add keyword 'as' while casting Bar.bar(MyInterface.class) as MyInterface

Comment: I need to be able to call `bar` from Java code as well, so it must return the correct type already.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface MyInterface {
    def foo()
}

interface AnotherInterface {
    def foo()
}

class MyClass {
    def foo() { "foo" }
}

class Bar {
    static <T> T bar(Class<T> type) {
        new MyClass().asType(type)
    }
}


MyInterface mi = Bar.bar(MyInterface)
assert mi.foo() == "foo"

AnotherInterface ai = Bar.bar(AnotherInterface)
assert ai.foo() == "foo"
```